# If someone has more than N invites left, don't award any more

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I have now collected over 40 invitations on Careers. I don't need any more right now.

Why not limit the total amount of unused invitations a user can collect?

I'm up to 55 now \o/

[image]
[image]

Comment: You could give them out...

Comment: @UndotheSnowman: When I thought someone would be interested in an invite, I have already given them one. And, I'm sorry to say, but Careers isn't *that* cool that I would spam everyone I know in tech with an invite.

Comment: Is having a number appear on a website somewhere really a problem for you somehow? Use a userscript to make it shop showing.

Comment: @Wooble: No, the number on the website doesn't really concern me. I just find the notification somewhat annoying. http://i.imgur.com/ubrsJ4r.png But maybe that's the point. To remind me that I should go over there, update my profile and send out a couple of invites ;)